# is there an R function by which you I can extract GAM summary output as a table to be presented in a document?

Tags: r, output, regression, summary, gam

I have run a GAM and obtained a summary output. I want to extract the output of summary into a table, so that I can use it in a document.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to present the summary of GAM output into a table, can you suggest me a way for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your gam model is called `gamfit`.
You can use `l <- as.list(summary(gamfit))` to store this in a list.
Then access the parts with `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]`, ...
The problem with this is that, depending on how many variables are used in the analysis, the data you want may move around and the list items aren't named.  If the model isn't going to change, then it's fine.

Also note that all the information about the model is stored in gamfit.
Explore this in the Rstudio Environment window or at the command line with `names(gamfit)`, followed by `gamfit$name_of_interest`.